# IE does not launch using RemoteWebDrivr TestNG

Tags: webdriver, testng

Could someone please help me resolve this issue. When I run my following code in TestNG I get the following error: "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;"

```
public class GoogleSearch2 {
    RemoteWebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities cap;
    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void searchTest2() throws MalformedURLException{
    System.out.println(browser);
    if(browser.equals("firefox")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\sqadri  \\Mozilla
        Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    }           
    else if(browser.equals("iexplore")){

    File file = new File("D:/Data/IEDriver/IEDriverServer.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
    cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using selenium grid then start your node passing the path of the IE driver. This worked for me.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig configNodes.json -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=<your path>/IEDriverServer.exe
```

Comment: Run it as Yuvaraj HK said and don't forget to put IDriverServer on your remote machine.

Also you don't need to add any system property to run FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Yuvaraj, thanks it worked. I have another issue with executing the scripts on IE from ant, I get errors for all imports regarding IE.